# loopback hasandbelongstomany relation table doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, relationship, loopbackjs

I have defined two models:
a 'part' model:

```
{
  "name": "part",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "assemblies": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "assembly",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and an 'assembly' models:

```
{
  "name": "assembly",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "parts": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "part"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

both models have an hasAndBelongToMany relation.

In a /server/boot/sample-model.js i have created some instance of this both models:

```
module.exports =  function(app){
  var Dev = app.dataSources.dev;
  var Customer = app.models.customer;
  var Order = app.models.order;
  var Part = app.models.part;
  var Assembly = app.models.assembly;

  Dev.automigrate(['customer', 'order', 'assembly', 'part'], function(err) {
    Customer.create([
      {name: 'nicolas'},
      {name: 'marie'},
      {name: 'cyril'}
    ], function(err, customers){
      Part.create([
        {name: 'boulon'},
        {name: 'ecrou'},
        {name: 'cheville'},
      ], function(err, part){
        //console.log(part[0])
        Assembly.create([
          {title: 'piece1'},
          {title: 'piece2'},
          {title: 'piece3'},
        ], function(err, assemblies){
          //console.log(assemblies[0])
          assemblies[0].parts.add(part[0], function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err)
            }
          })
        })
      })
    });
  });
}
```

but

```
assemblies[0].parts.add(part[0], function(err){
                if(err){
                  console.log(err)
                }
              })
```

end with error:

```
{ [Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'database_development.assemblypart' doesn't exist]
  code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
  errno: 1146,
  sqlState: '42S02',
  index: 0 }
```

why loopback doesn't create the assemblypart table in my database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue once and after many hours of struggling (using postgres connector), I've found several solutions.

Here's the shortest :

Instead of :

```
  Dev.automigrate(['customer', 'order', 'assembly', 'part'], function(err) {
    // Your code here
  });
```

Try using this :

```
  Dev.automigrate()
    .then(function(err) {
      // Your code here
    });
```

I don't know exactly why, but in the second case the junction table is created.

Can you try this and let me know if it works for you ? If it's not can you provide some place where I can inspect and try running your code ?

Comment: I've try, but that doesn't work. But i've add 'assemblypart' to the 

Dev.automigrate(['customer', 'order', 'assembly', 'part', 'assemblypart'], function(err) {
    // Your code here
  });


and the table was created in the database.

I don't understand why that's not in the doc. Maybe it's not the best practice ?

Comment: Actually I've had this problem only on sql connectors specially Postgres. If you read the doc somewhere hidden between two blocs, you'll see that automigrate and autoupdate are not supported by sql connectors.

It's easier to get your app running with mongo but do not rush the easy way and try to determine what you'll be in need for.

If your project grows you might even need multiple databases with a combination of sql, no-sql etc.

Comment: I do not necessarily need a Mysql database. I'll try with a mongo base. I'll keep you informed. thanks.